# Serried in ConTeXt heads

Tags: sectioning, context

I want to know how to use something similar to `alternative=serried` in ConTeXt heads, like sections or even chapters, e.g.

```
1. This is a section.- This is a nice text example. 

There's another line.

And another line.

2. Love and glory.- Another section to keep writing.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `alternative=text`:

```
\setuphead[section]
   [style=\bf,
    alternative=text,
    number=yes]


\starttext 
\startsection[title={This is a section.}]
  This is a nice text example.

  There's another line.

  And another line.
\stopsection

\startsection[title={Love and glory.}]
  Another section to keep writing.
\stopsection
\stoptext
```

[image]